# CAML Query to get items under folder\s ordered Ascending

Tags: caml-query

I am trying to retrieve all the documents within a specified folder (including subfolders) and order them Ascending. I am getting all the documents but they are not ordered.

This is what I have so far:

```
const libraryName = "Approved Policies and Procedures";
const groupFolderPath = `${this._pageContext.web.serverRelativeUrl}/Approved Policies and Procedures/1. Telkom Group`;
const corpFolderPath = `${this._pageContext.web.serverRelativeUrl}/Approved Policies and Procedures/4. Corp Centre`;

const groupQuery = `
    <View Scope="RecursiveAll">
      <Query>
        <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="Title" Ascending='True'/>
        </OrderBy>
        <Where>
            <And>
              <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="FSObjType" />
                <Value Type="Integer">0</Value>
              </Eq>
                <BeginsWith>
                  <FieldRef Name="FileRef" />
                  <Value Type="Text">${groupFolderPath}</Value>
                </BeginsWith>
            </And>
        </Where>
        </Query>
    </View>
  `;
```

I have tried adding the ORDERBY after the WHERE clause, but still not ordered!

Any help\guidance will be appreciated

Comment: Can you share the line where you use `groupQuery`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to order files by name, you have to use `FileLeafRef`and not `Title`

```
const groupQuery = `
    <View Scope="RecursiveAll">
      <Query>
        <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="FileLeafRef" Ascending='True'/>
        </OrderBy>
        <Where>
            <And>
              <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="FSObjType" />
                <Value Type="Integer">0</Value>
              </Eq>
                <BeginsWith>
                  <FieldRef Name="FileRef" />
                  <Value Type="Text">${groupFolderPath}</Value>
                </BeginsWith>
            </And>
        </Where>
        </Query>
    </View>
  `;
```

Comment: This resolved my issue, many thanks